# A private interface for classes in a module/hierarchy, like a family of classes?

Tags: javascript, oop

I was wondering if it was at all possible to construct a family of classes which know each other's secrets but have secrets for the outside world.

Some classes could share a common interface, allowing them to call each other and be nested in arbitrary ways, but keep this interface private so that the rest of the codebase can't possibly depend on / mess with it.

Is that a thing?

The only way I can think of to make it work is to actually have only one class with some branching inside, and I don't like this idea one bit. To my knowledge, there is no way to achieve this effect via inheritance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a particular reason you want to do this or is it just an intellectual curiosity

Comment: Would a module not satisfy your requirements? Classes in the module know each other, but only whatever the module exports will be visible to the outside world.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "common interface" or "nested in arbitrary ways". Neither of these things are private in JS if you have access to the class object.

Comment: You should give an example (the more realistic, the better) of what the classes could share, and what kind of interface you were envisioning, and what (if anything) they would make visible to the outside world. It would be a lot easier to show alternatives with a clearer question.

Comment: The question was inspired by real code but I find this concept more interesting than solving the original problem, which i am sure can be solved in a number of ways. I am not very comfortable in OO. I'll make an update with an example though.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a symbol as a key and don't export it.

```js
const sharedSecret: unique symbol = Symbol('sharedSecret')

export class A {
   [sharedSecret] = 'A'
}

export class B {
   [sharedSecret] = 'B'
}
```

Comment: Not exporting the symbol makes it harder to access, but not impossible. Symbol-keyed properties are useful for avoiding collisions, but they are not private or secret.

Comment: What you're looking for is protected properties. This is not possible in js. you can have private properties, but they are not inherited. You can (sort of) mimic protected properties by only referencing them from outside with get and set functions, but the actual property being got or set can still be viewed from outside directly

Comment: Well it's technically better than a TS-only private field on that regard, and you need to go out of your way to even notice it's there since symbols are not enumerable. It sends a signal that you should not worry about it or try to use it as a regular user. For stuff like meta programming or library "danger zone" features I think it's fine.